# Write data using I2C windows iot and Arduino

Tags: c#, arduino, raspberry-pi, i2c, windowsiot

So I have a Arduino and Raspberry pi 3 with windows IoT connected as show in the image below:
[[image]][1

I want to read from, and write to, the Arduino slave using the RPI as master with I2C. I have the following code so far:

C# Master:

```
private I2cDevice arduio; // Used to Connect to Arduino
private DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();

public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    Initialiasecom();
}

public async void Initialiasecom()
{
    var settings = new I2cConnectionSettings(0x40); // Slave Address of Arduino Uno 
    settings.BusSpeed = I2cBusSpeed.FastMode; // this bus has 400Khz speed

    string aqs = I2cDevice.GetDeviceSelector("I2C1"); // This will return Advanced Query String which is used to select i2c device
    var dis = await Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(aqs);
    arduio = await I2cDevice.FromIdAsync(dis[0].Id, settings);

    timer.Tick += Timer_Tick; // We will create an event handler 
    timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 500); // Timer_Tick is executed every 500 milli second
    timer.Start();
}

private async void Timer_Tick(object sender, object e)
{
    byte[] response = new byte[2];
    byte[] request = new byte[] { 0x40, 0x40 };

    try
    {
        arduio.Read(response); // this funtion will request data from Arduino and read it
        arduio.Write(request); // this function will send data to Arduino
    }
    catch (Exception p)
    {
        //Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog msg = new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog(p.Message);

        Debug.WriteLine(p.Message);

        //await msg.ShowAsync(); // this will show error message(if Any)
    }

    text.Text = response[0].ToString();
}
```

Slave Arduino:

```
include <Wire.h>
#define SLAVE_ADDRESS 0x40

byte response[1]; // this data is sent to PI

void setup() {
    Wire.begin(SLAVE_ADDRESS);                // join i2c bus with address slaveAddress
    Wire.onReceive(I2CReceived);
    Wire.onRequest(I2CRequest);
}

void loop() {
    delay(100);
}

// function that executes whenever data is requested by master
// this function is registered as an event, see setup()
void I2CRequest() {

    response[0] = (byte)17;
    Wire.write(response, 2); // return data to PI
}

// function that executes whenever data is received from master
// this function is registered as an event, see setup()
void I2CReceived(int howMany) {
    Serial.println("test");

    while (1 < Wire.available()) { // loop through all but the last
        char c = Wire.read(); // receive byte as a character
        Serial.print(c);         // print the character
    }
    int x = Wire.read();    // receive byte as an integer
    Serial.println(x);         // print the integer
}
```

I can successfully read data from the Arduino and print them to the textblock on windows IoT. But I also want to write text to the Arduino. I tried something but it isn't working. Can someone please explain how to write data.

I really need some help and I'm no professional programmer so please keep it as simple as possible. If something is wrong with my current code please comment so I can try to improve my code.

Comment: In the provided code,  `//Wire.onReceive(I2CReceived);` is commented, so the event is not registered. Please open this code to register Receive event, and then try again.

Comment: Sorry uploaded wrong code, still doesn't work with it uncommented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is due to the missing of `Serial.begin`,in fact the data sent from master to slaver has been received,just not printed.Please try again with the following code on slaver.

```
#include <Wire.h>
#define SLAVE_ADDRESS 0x40

byte response[1]; // this data is sent to PI
static int index = 0;

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600); 
    Wire.begin(SLAVE_ADDRESS);                // join i2c bus with address         slaveAddress
    Wire.onReceive(I2CReceived);
    Wire.onRequest(I2CRequest);    
}

void loop() {
    delay(100);
}

// function that executes whenever data is requested by master
// this function is registered as an event, see setup()
void I2CRequest() {
    Serial.println("I2C-Request");
    response[0] = (byte) index ++ ;
    Wire.write(response, 2); // return data to PI
}

// function that executes whenever data is received from master
// this function is registered as an event, see setup()
void I2CReceived(int howMany) {
    Serial.println("I2C-Received");

    while (1 < Wire.available()) { // loop through all but the last
      char c = Wire.read(); // receive byte as a character
      Serial.print(c);         // print the character
    }
    int x = Wire.read();    // receive byte as an integer
    Serial.println(x);         // print the integer
}
```

I tested with my Arduino UNO,it works.The received data could be shown in serial monitor.

[image]

Comment: I would like to send a string/char instead, you have any idea how I would do that.